# Spark - Simple Linear Regression

Tags: apache-spark

I am a newbie to Spark and tried some simple linear regression. Don't seem to be able to figure out how to fix this error.
Can some expert please help ?
The dataset is http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00294/

```
from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
pp_df = spark.read.csv('D:/OneDrive/MachineLearning/Spark
      /CCPP/CCPP/Folds5x2_pp.csv',header= True,inferSchema=True)
vectorAssembler = VectorAssembler (inputCols=["AT","V","AP","RH"], 
       outputCol = "features")
vpp_df = vectorAssembler.transform(pp_df)
vd = vpp_df.select("features","PE")
vdN = vd.selectExpr("features as features", "PE as label")
lr = LinearRegression(featuresCol="features", labelCol = "label")
lr_model = lr.fit(vdN)

  pp_df.take(1)
  [Row(AT=14.96, V=41.76, AP=1024.07, RH=73.17, PE=463.26)]

  pp_df.dtypes

  [('AT', 'double'),
   ('V', 'double'),
   ('AP', 'double'),
   ('RH', 'double'),
   ('PE', 'double')]

  vpp_df.take(1)

  [Row(AT=14.96, V=41.76, AP=1024.07, RH=73.17, PE=463.26, 
   features=DenseVector([14.96, 41.76, 1024.07, 73.17]))]

  vdN.take(1) 
  [Row(features=DenseVector([14.96, 41.76, 1024.07, 73.17]), label=463.26)]
```

Here is the error that I am seeing

---

Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 lr_model = lr.fit(vdN)

```
  D:\Spark\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\ml\base.py in 
         fit(self, dataset, params)
        130                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
        131             else:
    --> 132                 return self._fit(dataset)
        133         else:
        134             raise ValueError("Params must be either a param 
                         map or a list/tuple of param maps, "
```

Comment: It should be a problem related to your original dataframe after you read it with `spark.read.csv` because I ran your code without any error after downloading the data (I used sheet 5 of `Folds5x2_pp.xlsx`). Can you post the output of `pp_df.show()` and  `pp_df.dtypes` in your code?

Comment: I get this `>>> lr_model.coefficients`
`DenseVector([-1.9775, -0.2339, 0.0621, -0.1581])` using your code (except the reading part), I'm using Spark 1.6 and Python 2.7 so I read the data using `sqlContext`

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43355341/spark-pipeline-error/43378263 You probably have missing values and/or your columns are not given in numeric format (they should be of type double)

Comment: user322778, thanks for your kind help. I changed the file to have just 1 row and it still does not work. The data types are float as can be seen from the printout. Something fundamental is wrong in my code !!!

Comment: Can you tell me the output of `pp_df.show()` and `pp_df.dtypes` in your code? Again, I ran your code successfully by reading correctly the data and making sure the format is correct.

Comment: +-----+-----+-------+-----+------+
|   AT|    V|     AP|   RH|    PE|
+-----+-----+-------+-----+------+
|14.96|41.76|1024.07|73.17|463.26|
+-----+-----+-------+-----+------+

Comment: [('AT', 'double'),
 ('V', 'double'),
 ('AP', 'double'),
 ('RH', 'double'),
 ('PE', 'double')]

Comment: user322778, the outputs for those 2 commands are printed above. I am using Python 3 and Spark 2.3.1. Maybe a new bug or something. It is really frustrating that I cannot run this example on my local spark. Databricks seems to be fine, but I want to run locally because I want to run the data import APIs from my computer and pull data from websites instead of downloading /uploading to files and making it work in Databricks ( besides I only have the community edition). Thanks for your help though